# UV/texture doesnt scale on one face

Tags: texturing, uv, sculpting, uv-image-editor, displacement

So I've been learning Blender for a week now and I love it very much. I've been trying to do a teddy bear tutorial and anyway my texture is screwed up on one of the faces. Is it a sculpting thing I messed up or is it something else?

What it looks like on the belly but everywhere else its all good :
[image: belly]

Thanks

Edit : added UV layout
[image]

Comment: Your UVs seam very stretched. Can you show an image of the UV layout? Also how did you get the texture?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I added the UV layout. The texture is the Wool Fabric 1 from textures.com

Comment: It looks you need more seams. Try to cut in half vertically your model with seams. Like the sewing seams in real life.